# Applescript code messy, how to fix

Tags: applescript

```
display dialog "Play Nillys Realm?" buttons {"Yes please", "No"} default button 1

if result = {button returned: "Yes please"} then
  display dialog "Long time loading, u think?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} 
end if

if result = {button returned:"No"} then
  tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat 5 times
        open location "http://test.nillysrealm.com"
        activate
    end repeat


    if result = {button returned:"Yes"} then
      tell application "Google Chrome"
        repeat 10 times
          open location "http://test.nillysrealm.com"
          activate
        end repeat
```

thats my code and it is a MESS. Can anyone help me fix? It will never load

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to help in your script, because reading it, I do not understand what you want to do. However you are not using the 'Result' variable correctly. This variable always contains the result of the last dialog, so when you have 2 dialog box, any test of that variable will always give you the result of the second dialog, never the first one.

The solution is to specifically assign the result to a separate variable, like in example bellow :

```
set Dialog1 to display dialog "do you agree ?" buttons {"Yes please", "No"} default button 1
if button returned of Dialog1 is "Yes please" then
-- do something here when user click "yes please"
else
-- do somthing here when user click "No"
end if
```